# Redirecting from lower case to upper case

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I'm having some issues trying to redirect picture galleries from a website.
I'm using an asp.net plataform with IIS7, but I would like to do the redirect in the webconfig file.

I would like to redirect this:

http://testurl.com/imagegallery/150/galleryname

to this:

http://testurl.com/imageGallery/150/galleryname

Any idea how to do this?
Thank you =]

Comment: both url are same. Then what do you want to do additionally?

Comment: They should be treated same; it should not be redirected. Is your application expecting upper case?

Comment: I just wanted it to show the uppercase "G" on the browser.